# Spark-Cassandra connector setup environment

Tags: android, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

Anyone have an experience in setting up the Spark-Cassandra connector in window OS and android studio?
link to download the API: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector
I been try to setup the API whole day but failed.

Comment: Android studio? Why do you need spark in Android?
Actually Android does not run real java, so I do not expect to work.
If you are going to use it as IDE, remember that it base on Java 6, but latest connector required Java 8.

Comment: Currently i am doing a project  that require the mlib of cassandra spark. That why i need it